# Converting key+n-values text file to a CSV file

Tags: awk, sed, csv

Newbie on this site, so apologies if I ask this question badly:

I have a text file in the following format:

```
file: abc
value: 123
value: 234
value: 567
file: def
value: 999
file: ghi
value: 123
value: 999
```

My goal is to write a bash script that converts this text to CSV format, where the `file` value is repeated for each row. The data above needs to look like this:

```
abc,123
abc,234
abc,567
def,999
ghi,123
ghi,999
```

I have been trying with `sed` but don't see how to remember the file name across multiple lines. I'm guessing this might be easier with `awk` but I haven't "grawked" awk yet.

Would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `awk` command sets the `awk` variable `file` to the value of the `file` key whenever such a key is found (the key is the first field on the line, the value is the second).  If the current line has no `file` key, the current value of the `file` variable is outputted together with the value of the current line.

```bash
$ awk -F ': ' 'BEGIN { OFS="," } $1 == "file" { file = $2; next } { print file, $2 }' file
abc,123
abc,234
abc,567
def,999
ghi,123
ghi,999
```

Note that this does not attempt to quote the values correctly for CSV and that it assumes that no value contains the field delimiter `:`  (colon+space).

---

With `sed`:

```bash
sed -n \
    -e '/^file: /  { s///; h; }' \
    -e '/^value: / { s///; G; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/p; }' file
```

When a `file:` line is found, the `file:`  prefix string is stripped off and the remainder is stored in the hold space.

When a `value:` line is found, the `value:`  prefix string is stripped off, and the text in the hold-space is appended to the end of the buffer with a literal newline character as the delimiter.  The newline-delimited parts of the buffer are swapped (newline replaced by a comma) and outputted.

The result is the same as what is expected.

This does not have the restriction that the values after the initial `key:`  string can't include a colon+space. Again, the final output will not have any special CSV encoding of the text, so fields containing embedded commas and double quotes would confuse a CSV parser.

---

The following modifies the input by adding an empty line between each line in the original file.  This makes the file a valid "XTAB" file with `:`  as the key-value delimiter.  This is then read by Miller (`mlr`), which is aware of the special quoting rules of CSV and that can read the XTAB format.

Miller reads the records from the `awk` output, and performs a "fill-down" operation with the `file` data, assigning the previous `file` value to each of the records that do not have one.

The subsequent "filter" operation removes all records that do not have a `value` field.

The data is then outputted without a CSV header.

```bash
awk '{ print; print "" }' file | 
mlr --ixtab --ips ': ' \
    --ocsv --headerless-csv-output \
    fill-down -f file then filter -x 'is_absent($value)'
```

I've modified the test data to show that this is able to properly produce fully compliant CSV output even if the input contains commas and quotes:

```bash
$ cat file
file: test: here's a test
value: this is, the value
value: another so called "value"
file: abc
value: 123
value: 234
value: 567
file: def
value: 999
file: ghi
value: 123
value: 999
```

```bash
$ awk '{ print; print "" }' file | mlr --ixtab --ips ': ' --ocsv --headerless-csv-output fill-down -f file then filter -x 'is_absent($value)'
"this is, the value",test: here's a test
"another so called ""value""",test: here's a test
123,abc
234,abc
567,abc
999,def
123,ghi
999,ghi
```